# how to add sub figure on MNRAS LATEX paper?

Tags: latex, miktex, overleaf

I have been trying to add subfigure captions on my document but couldnot find any. kindly help
i am attaching an result i am getting [image]
need to add caption without changing the figure number. This is a MNRAS paper using double coulmn format.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par 
    \end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely require a solution involving the `multicol` environment then the following addition from the `subcaption` package would work

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \subcaptionbox{Caption\label{fig:1}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\par 
            \subcaptionbox{Caption\label{fig:2}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\par 
        \end{multicols}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \subcaptionbox{Caption\label{fig:3}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\par
            \subcaptionbox{Caption\label{fig:4}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}}\par
        \end{multicols}
    \caption{Caption here}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that there are many possible other solutions ; some of which use `subfigure`, `minipage` and other.